# Swift version of Matlab's vector find?

Tags: arrays, swift, vector

I'm looking for vector (fast) code that does what matlab `find` function does *without* loops.  `find` returns both value and index for a given function.  Swift's filter, map or reduce do not return indices.

example

```
X = [18 3 1 11; 8 10 11 3; 9 14 6 1; 4 3 15 21]

[row,col] = find(X>0 & X<10,3)

row =

     2
     3
     4


col =

     1
     1
     1
```

From the matlab docs

> [row,col] = find(___) returns the row and column subscripts of each
>   nonzero element in array X using any of the input arguments in
>   previous syntaxes.

Comment: *"find returns both value and index ..."* I cannot see that from your example or the Matlab documentation, the result are only row/column indices. – Do you need a method for "matrices" (which are not a built-in  Swift type) or just for arrays (aka "vectors") ?

Comment: For now, I'd be happy to get started with vectors and then move up to matrices.

Comment: Have you looked into Accelerate framework. I don't have all methods in memory, but you might find something performant there

Comment: I spent some time grepping through the docs but didn't find results for vector but I think there could be for a matrix???  It was a bit confusing reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns a sequence of index/element pairs which can
be filtered:

```
let vec = [18, 3, 1, 11, 8, 10, 11, 3, 9]
let result = filter(enumerate(vec), { (idx, elem) in elem > 2 && elem < 10 } )
println(result) // [(1, 3), (4, 8), (7, 3), (8, 9)]
```

Or, if you only want the indices:

```
let indexes = filter(enumerate(vec), { (idx, elem) in elem > 2 && elem < 10 } ).map { $0.0 }
println(indexes) // [1, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Great, to move on to a matrix, would you need to pull in the accelerate framework?

Comment: @GAlexander: You *can* represent a matrix as a nested array, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051490/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936824/what-is-the-syntax-for-multidimensional-array-in-swift or similar threads. The methods from the Accelerate framework are probably faster, but they use pure C data types, which makes it a bit more difficult to use them in Swift functions like `filter`. I do not have much experience with Accelerate, so I cannot advise you on that.

Comment: I am using them. for FFT with Swift arrays. Should work well.

Comment: @Volker: Has Accelerate methods to find indices of vector/matrix elements satisfying a predicate?

Comment: @MartinR as in my comment to the question i don't have the full functions in memory, but when browsing last I think I slaw one chance . Might have needed to functions like a threshold one first and then the index/value extraction. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [Swift Matrix Library](http://scottsievert.github.io/swix/) may be appropriate here. It implements [argwhere](http://scottsievert.github.io/swix/ndarray.html#ndarray.helper_functions.argwhere) along with many scientific functions.

This library was inspired by Python and Matlab. This framework calls the Accelerate framework from Swift and hence is pretty speedy (speed tests can be found in *[Speed](http://scottsievert.github.io/swix/speed.html)*).

Further features can be found in *[Examples](http://scottsievert.github.io/swix/examples.html)* but it provides the following features:

- provides an `ndarray` and `matrix` class. All mathematical operators (`+-*/`) call Accelerate functions.
- "Simple math" functions (pow/log/exp/sqrt/etc) on ndarray or matrix call Accelerate
- allows access to easy initing functions (ones/zeros/etc)
- More complex math can also be found: `eig, svd, fft, solve, dot, inv` are all implemented.

Installation details can be found in *[Install](http://scottsievert.github.io/swix/installation.html)*.

*(note: I am the author)*